# Reading a tab separated file in R

Tags: r, csv

I'm trying to read a file in R but the fourth record appears as a new line (see attached). After the third line, there's no tab, just two spaces. I'm using this code:

```
df = read.delim("text.txt", header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, quote = "")
```

UPDATE: the third line has "¬" at the end.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

use the `sep` argument of `read.delim` to specify the separator. in this case you would need

```
df = read.delim("text.txt", header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, quote = "", sep = "\t")
```

Comment: also I think the `quote = " "` argument is unnecessary

Comment: Unfortunately, "\t" didn't help.

Comment: "invalid 'sep' value: must be one byte" for forward slash

Comment: sorry, I did mean `"\t"`, i feel silly now. edited my answer . If that doesn't work perhaps your file is separated with a mixture of tabs and spaces - if you could post the example data it would help